# CodeIgniter - Rewriting url

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting

There are many tutorials that talk about deleting index.php from the url. But I want one step forward of it.

The link is: www.example.com/index.php/controller/function/single-variable
I want it like: www.example.com/some-name-that-i-put/single-variable

I cannot find a tutorial to do such a thing. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**i wasnt sure whether you were wanting to do direct URL rewrites how CI does it out of the box or not... but this is how you do URL Rewrites:**

your class/function/id `example.com/news/article/13` transposes to: `example.com/class/function/ID`

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

you can set this by doing two things:
in your config.php file under application/config/ edit these:

```
approx line 80: $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'; // i set this to request_URI as it always works for me..
approx line 93: $config['url_suffix'] = '.html'; // this is optional, if you want /13.html
approx line 62: $config['index_page'] = ''; //set this to blank
```

create a .htaccess in http root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

**This is how you do URI Route changes**

if you want to change the organization of the URI you can use URI Routes defined in routes.php as described here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: URI route change is the one I was looking for.

Comment: in which case you simple use a regex to define the remapping.. the user guide lays it out in plain english.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this CodeIgniter user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/routing.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this codeigniter user guide
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**
in your config file place these

```
     $config['uri_protocol']    = 'AUTO';
     $config['url_suffix'] = '';
     $config['index_page'] = '';
     $config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
     $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

after this make a .htaccess file at your root directory and put this

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

this will Definitely help you